# How to identify model is changed before submitting to server?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

We have MVC application. We have a requirement if user changes any data on the page and tries to navigate away from the page without saving then we need to show some "Are you sure?" kind of message.

Challenge here is how do i identify data is changed? our typical design pattern is as below

```
public class MyController:Controller
{
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
      var model = LoadModelFromDB();
      return View(model);
   }
}
```

and then we bind the model to view using Html helper extension methods.
On client side How do i identify if the model is  dirty before submitting the data to the server?

Comment: You need javascript. One option is to compare each controls `defaultValue` property (`defaultChecked` for checkbox) with the `value` property

Answer (score 0):

This is an operation that happens entirely on the client - it has nothing to do with the Model in MVC.

You can accomplish this by attaching an event handler to the [`onbeforeunload` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) using JavaScript, and providing some additional logic to test the form elements for changes.

I have contributed to an open source project that does just this, helps to fix differences between browsers, as well as monitors the form elements for changes, allows plugging in different dialog frameworks, and wraps it up into a nice jQuery plugin named [`Dirty Forms`](https://github.com/snikch/jquery.dirtyforms).

Comment: what if i serialize the form on document ready and store the value in variable & and then again serialize it before navigating away, and compare both serialized values, will that work?

Comment: I haven't tried that, but it might work. I am skeptical that something might go awry if you have AJAX on the page dynamically changing form attributes, though.

Comment: ye, i have to sereailize and store every time DOM changes